# Prototype.js: select elements with id starts with?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, selector

There are tags with attributes `id` like this

```
<span id="attr35"></span>
<span id="attr44"></span>
<span id="attr23"></span>
```

Need to set the style to them like this (last two digits might be any)

```
$("span[id=attr???]").setStyle({'display':'inline'});
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Assuming that this selector syntax is built on top of CSS selector syntax (and therefore `document.querySelector()`), I'd suggest: `$("span[id^=attr]")` but I'm unfamiliar with Prototype.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use valid [Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/) selectors.

```
$("span[id^=attr]")
```

If you want more than one match, use `$$`

```
$$("span[id^=attr]")
```

---

Oops, one more issue. You should use `.invoke` if you are getting multiple matches. You can't call `setStyle` directly on the returned set.

```
$$("span[id^=attr]").invoke("setStyle", ...)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since version 1.5.1 the [`$$` function](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/) supports the attribute-startswith-selector `^=`:

```
$$('[id^="attr"]').invoke("setStyle",{display:'inline'});
```

Comment: You need to use `.invoke` to call `setStyle` on a collection. ;)

Comment: You're welcome. I forgot at first too. It's been a while since I used prototypejs.

Answer (score 2):

```
$$('[id^="attr"]').invoke("setStyle",{'display':'inline'});
```

Comment: You need to use `.invoke` to call `setStyle` on a collection. ;)